# Toxic workplace environment and my role

Tags: toxic-culture

I am working in an organization managed by military officers for last 4.5 years. The organization was started around 6 years ago. I sit in a large hall with 14 more engineers.
When I initially joined, all of us directly reported to our director. After a dispute arose in the lab, the director assigned one of the engineers, Mr. AAK, as the group senior. I had a great working relation with Mr. AAK and things ran smoothly. After approximately two years, Mr. AAK decided to stop acting as group senior and moved to another office. Later, I came to know a little about his decision to quit. Some of the people in our group acted like bully (for the sake of this discussion, we will call them the group A); they bullied another engineer, Mr. YS, to the extent where he had recurring suicidal thoughts. In that time frame, a highly competent engineer from MIT joined our organization, and he too was bullied and within two years, he left and went back to the US. Once Mr. AAK moved to another office, I was assigned to be the group senior. I do not want to brag but I am extremely good at what I do, at least compared to other people in our group. However, I am also really bad at managing people and severely lack management skills. Furthermore, I have a highly inflated ego and I am very sensitive about my respect.
Fast forward two more years, our organization hired a civilian PhD (I hold an MS in relevant field), therefore, he become our senior man. Additionally, two more deputy directors from were assigned to our organization.
Now I am no longer the senior man, but I am still the most senior in the group. I try to be courteous and expect the same from my peers. If I have problem with someone, I discuss it with them privately or I keep my mouth shut.
One of the guys in the bully group, Mr. AM, has the habit of passing sarcastic remarks on almost everything. Once I asked him politely to move some computers from one place to another. On which, he sarcastically replied "Yes, I will also mop the floor for you". Keep in mind that most engineers in my country think that manual labour is beneath their dignity. I had been ignoring his remarks for some time, but at that moment, his remarks infuriated me, and I gave him a shut up call at the moment. This started a chain of events. When we got back to our main office, that bully group started showing “passive-aggressive” behavior. Since we all sat in a large hall, I could clearly hear their complaints about their treatment and about me. Eight months on this behavior has not ceased.
A similar incident happened recently, I had to assign one engineer from our group to be posted at new setup in another city. Although I had the authority to assign anyone I wished, I announced that I needed a volunteer. When no one came forward, I asked three engineers who were from that city to choose among themselves. One of these three is the “class clown” and started making stupid remarks. Another resisted, and I on the spot gave her a shut up call and asked her to decide among themselves or I will decide as I deem fit. They decided among themselves and the lady engineer went to the bully group and started ranting about how she was mistreated, how she was in the right etc.
I am getting tired of all this. I am looking to identify what is wrong with our office environment. Who is the culprit? Where did I go wrong so that I don’t repeat the same mistakes in future.

Comment: Any chance you can shorten this down a bit? I'm afraid not many people will read to the end.

Comment: @nvoigt I have deleted unnecessary details. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Paragraphs help make the text easier to read. A long wall of text is, for many, too much effort.

Answer (score 2):

What a difficult situation!  Are you familiar with either of the books, "Leadership and Self-deception" or "The Outward Mindset" by the Arbinger Institute?  You are perfectly situated to apply their core principles.  In short: You want to INCREASE your level of respect and value for your co-workers, while simultaneously asking for better (more respectful, responsive, etc.) behavior.  It can be difficult to separate these things in our minds, but asking people to do things that are beneath them is NOT the same as devaluing them.  If you really value your people, the entire way you interact with them will change, even if you're asking for the same things.  My recommendation is to do everything you can to see your teammates as people, whose needs, obstacles, and interests matter like yours matter, and then just see how everything changes when the way you see them is different.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will definitely read the books you have mentioned. I have always been kind and sympathetic towards my colleagues. To share just one example, my partner was sick and I took her to the hospital. During her checkup, I received a call from the lady engineer mentioned in the question and I went straight to office to help her. She was under heavy criticism from one of the Deputy Director and I helped her.

Comment: Frankly, the only thing I want from them is discuss whatever problems they have with me or show some courtesy and discuss when I am not around. I believe this is unfair to me that I am present in the same room and they are discussing my behavior without making me part of their discussion and thereby giving me no chance of justifying my position.

Comment: That sounds so painful.  There are a number of things to look at / try.  If you can discover the root cause of their frustration, that will help.  They likely won't share with you unless they feel safe.  The sense of entitlement they might feel as engineers in a 3rd-world country might present a barrier that you will want to a) acknowledge, and b) convert into something positive, like an opportunity for them to lift the community.  But yeah, look into making it safe to speak up, help them know that you'll not just hear them out but act on what they share, and start building trust between y'all

Answer (score 0):

> I am also really bad at managing people and severely lack management skills. Furthermore, I have a highly inflated ego and I am very sensitive about my respect.

You're in the wrong position. The major reason for hiring 3rd World locals for leadership positions is that they can handle the locals. First World people cannot teach that skill, all they can do is procrastinate for a while and then remove them for the good of the company.